# Powershell catching exception type

Tags: powershell, exception

Is there a convenient way to catch types of exceptions and inner exceptions for try-catch purposes?

Example code:

```
$a = 5
$b = Read-Host "Enter number" 
$c = $a / $b #error if $b -eq 0
$d = get-content C:\I\Do\Not\Exist
```

Row #3 will generate a runtime error with an inner exception (EDIT: fixed this command $Error[1].Exception.InnerException.GetType()), row #4 will generate a "standard"(?) type of exception ($Error[0].Exception.GetType()).

Is it possible to get the desired result from both of these with the same line of code?

Ad1: error from row 3

```
At -path-:3 char:1

+ $c = $a / $b #error if $b -eq 0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Ad2: error from row 4

```
get-content : Cannot find path 'C:\I\Do\Not\Exist' because it does not exist.

At -path-:4 char:6

+ $d = get-content C:\I\Do\Not\Exist

+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\I\Do\Not\Exist:String) 
[Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException    
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Edit: To make it clear, I want the result to return DivideByZeroException and ItemNotFoundException in some way

Comment: Have you tried using `$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"` ? That will just let the code run through errors.

Comment: I think you are mistaken `$Error[1].InnerException` - there is no such property. You can do `$Error[1].Exception` just as with the other one. Not sure what you want.

Comment: @marsze My bad, it was $Error[1].Exception.InnerException.GetType()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you can explicitly catch specific exception types:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

try {
    1 / 0
}
catch [System.DivideByZeroException] {
    $_.Exception.GetType().Name
}

try {
    Get-Item "c:\does-not-exist"
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
    $_.Exception.GetType().Name
}
```

The `DivideByZeroException` is basically just the InnerException of `RuntimeException`, and theoretically, the InnerExceptions could be endlessly nested:

```
catch {
    $exception = $_.Exception
    do {
        $exception.GetType().Name
        $exception = $exception.InnerException
    } while ($exception)
}
```

**BUT** you can handle `RuntimeException` as a special case. Even PowerShell does so. Look at the first code example. The catch-block is reached even though the type of the **inner** exception is specified.

You could do something similar yourself:

```
catch {
    $exception = $_.Exception
    if ($exception -is [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] -and $exception.InnerException) {
        $exception = $exception.InnerException
    }
    $exception.GetType().Name
}
```

**NOTE** that you need one try-catch per command, if you want to catch both exceptions. Else the 2nd will not be executed if the 1st one fails. Also you have to specify `$ErrorActionPreference` to `"Stop"` to catch also non-terminating exceptions.

Comment: This answers it nicely, endlessly nested InnerExceptions explain, why the type could not be determined by a relatively easy command.
I might use this code as a find-the-type-of-exception, I hope that you do not mind.

Comment: Instead of `Name` you might want to use `FullName` to get the namespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that you can create a sorted list of exception types like so:

```
function Get-Exceptions {
  [OutputType([String[]])]
  [String[]]$Exceptions = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | foreach {
    try {
      $_.GetExportedTypes().BaseType | where { $_.Fullname -match 'Exception' }
    } catch {}
  }
  return $Exceptions | Sort-Object -Unique
}
```

It can be used to find the appropriate exception type like so:

```
$Exceptions = Get-Exceptions
Write-Output $Exceptions
```