# PowerShell - How to log FULL exception including all useful details?

Tags: powershell, exception, logging

It has been a while since the last time I wrote a powershell script. The first thing I did is implement a logging function into my script but now I noticed that no matter if I log $_ or $_.Exception in a catch-block, there is always some information missing when the log is written to a file. How can I log the exception with all details like line number, stack trace and so on to a file without writing like 5 lines of code just for formatting the exception manually? Is there really no standard way of doing this in powershell?

Comment: `start-transcript`?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it depends on exception.

Every exception is an instance of Exception class or [one of derivatives.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception)

This means that all Exceptions guaranteed to have basic properties and methods listed in [MSDN Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data) doc, but additionally Exceptions can have it's own properties or methods. For example, `ArgumentException` is derivative from `Exception`, but is has an optional `ParamName` property.

You can catch *predicted* exceptions using [different catchers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195677/1936966) or you can get all properties using, for example, Get-Member, and log them. But `catch` block should not be complex.

---

Additionally, try using Start-Transcript instead of custom logging. Maybe this will be enough for your needs. Don't forget to set **compression** flag on folder where transcriptions will be written to.

Comment: I am not talking about exception-specific properties. All I need are the line number(s), stack trace, exception message and everything else that would be useful for debugging a problem, just like what you get when calling Exception.ToString() in C# / VB.NET. Start-Transcript would not work in my situation because it does not give me enough control about what I am logging.

Comment: There are links to Exception properties. As you see, there is both full message and stacktrace you want. Just output it